# Using burst compiler without ECS in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wonder if I can use burst compiler without using entity component system in unity, and if it's possible how effective is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. You can put [BurstCompile] over any IJob and it will speed up this job.
The speed depends on your task.
If you want to do some benchmarks, be sure to toggle off the JobsDebugger, the Leak Detection and enable Synchronus Compilation for Burst (otherwise Burst Jobs are compiled asynchronously while you are playing the game).
Also it helps to use the fast Mathematics Package in your IJobs and using [ReadOnly] wherever you can.